# Setting environment variables on cmd. Help needed

Tags: variables, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

Trying to set on variable up in my Command Prompt but not sure what syntax to use.

I've tried:

```
SET %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar helloworld.jar=HELLO_WORLD
SET HELLO_WORLD
```

and also:

```
SET "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar helloworld.jar=HELLO_WORLD"
SET HELLO_WORLD
```

None of them seem to work. Anyone have any ideas how to get a variable for the above?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure, what you want to achieve:  creating an env-variable, that holds the java-Path as well as

Comment: Pro tip. Use `help set` on the command prompt to get help on the `set` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to place the variable-name in front auf the equal-sign and the commandline:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set HELLO_WORLD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar helloworld.jar

C:\Windows\system32>set HELLO_WORLD
HELLO_WORLD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar helloworld.jar
```

Comment: Thanks! That works fine, but only when I'm in that session. If I exit, so does this variable. Is there a way to make this variable permanent?

Comment: you might use `setx` instead of  `set` (enter   `setx /?` for more details)